WooCommerce – Product variation single price changes after delay
Hi i Have a website in which price of variable product displays after some delay.(https://ajantasoya.com/shop/product/nutri-zero-cholesterol-soyabean-oil/). It would be great if anybody can help
Below mentioned are the codes which i have used to hide the price range and double pricing
add_filter('woocommerce_variable_price_html', 'bbloomer_variation_price_format_min', 9999, 2 );

function bbloomer_variation_price_format_min( $price, $product ) {
   $prices = $product->get_variation_prices( true );
   $min_price = current( $prices['price'] );
   $max_price = end( $prices['price'] );
   $min_reg_price = current( $prices['regular_price'] );
   $max_reg_price = end( $prices['regular_price'] );
   if ( $min_price !== $max_price || ( $product->is_on_sale() && $min_reg_price === $max_reg_price ) ) {
      $price = 'From: ' . wc_price( $min_price ) . $product->get_price_suffix();
   }
   return $price;
}

